# How to install EditorMD in laravel

Tags: laravel, markdown

I am trying to install editorMD but i am struggling since the documentation is in chinese, I have used the npm install but I cant seem to get it set up and working on laravel.

Comment: This can help you https://pandao.github.io/editor.md/en.html

Comment: I have tried to use that, however the basic example that they have to get the editor get up and running doesnt seem to work for me